# Magento backend better structure for static blocks

Tags: magento

We have many static blocks, which we include within our category pages. Is there a way to organize the blocks a little better in the magento backend instead of one list? Maybe an extension to create folders?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Depending on what you have in your static blocks, you could look at using categories instead of static blocks. I remember experimenting with this a couple of years ago but as I didn't have much static content I went the static blocks route.

Answer (score 0):

You can categorize them using their code (the identifier) and then use the filter.

#### A typical example is

- `footer_info`
- `footer_links_internal`
- `footer_links_external`
- `footer_links_social`

Now if I look for the footer blocks that contain links, I filter by code "footer_links_". Of course you have to follow your naming convention consequently and rembember it.

Sorry, no better way out of the box. An extension that changes the interface so that you can browse "folders" would be possible but I don't know of any existing one.

Comment: Thank you for that.. that is what I'm currently doing. Something like:

block_category_footer_....

Is there another option?